# Is it possible to output two different materials with Join Geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When I set two materials for two geometries and then join the geometries the material is wiped. It works for each individually but when joined it fails.

[image]

Is it possible?

Edit:

Here's the full tree
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior, neither with geometry created in *Geometry Nodes*, nor with instances included via `Object Info` (tested in **3.1.2** and **3.2**). Can you give us some more information?

Comment: I"ve updated the post

Answer (score 1):

you used "mesh to points" which "kills" the mesh, because points and edges are not rendered/shown. You need faces so that you can see something (and color).

Mute the "mesh to points" and your "delete geometry" nodes and the wonder will happen.

Comment: I see it the same way. `Set Material` works in this form only in the domain *Faces*. The [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/material/set_material.html) also says: *"volumes and point clouds only support a single material, in these cases a field input will be ignored"*

Comment: @quellenform Didn't realize points only supported one material. Thanks! I've used one material with a mix RGB node and it's the result as desired.